# Limit number of characters in input fields without editing HTML

Tags: javascript, plugins, wordpress, maxlength

I'm building a database of people on a WordPress website using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/).
I want to limit the number of characters the user can enter in certain fields (`textarea` and `input type="text"`) in the signup form. Since I'm using a plugin, I can't edit the HTML of the page, so I can't just use the `maxlength` attribute.

How can I limit the number of characters the user can enter - and preferably also show a remaining characters count - without access to HTML? Can you tell me which files to edit, what code to use and where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to set the max length as well as append: a remaining character count

```
$("input").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var maxLength = 50;
    $this.attr('maxlength', maxLength);

    var el = $("<span class=\"character-count\">" + maxLength + "</span>");
    el.insertAfter($this);

    $this.bind('keyup', function() {
        var cc = $this.val().length;

        el.text(maxLength - cc);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0vk3c245/

You would just need to specify which input you want to apply the function to by altering `"input"` on the first line as well as changing the `maxLength` variable based on your max characters allowed for each. You could modify this function to take in parameters for multiple fields as well.

Here is a modified version that lets you apply this to multiple inputs:

http://jsfiddle.net/0vk3c245/1/

Comment: You'd have to add it to one of your themes Javascript files or create a new Javascript file and enqueue it in your `functions.php` file: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy to do with MagJS.

Here is a full working example:

HTML :

```
<div id="limit">
  <h2>Characters left: <length/></h2>
  <input>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var demo = {}

demo.view = function(state, props) {

  state.textarea = state.input = { 

    _oninput: function() {

      state.length = props.limit - this.value.length;

      if (this.value.length > props.limit) {
        alert('max length reached:' + props.limit)
        this.value = this.value.substr(0, props.limit)
      }
    }
  }
}

var props = {
  limit: 10,
}

mag.module("limit", demo, props)
```

Here is link to working example: http://jsbin.com/sabefizuxi/edit?html,js,output

Hope that helps!

Comment: But as I wrote, I can't edit the HTML, so I cant do this: `<div id="limit">`
`<h2>Characters left: <length/></h2>`
`<input>`
`<textarea></textarea>`
`</div>`

Comment: Hi, that's perfectly ok. You can effect any html that was just an example. If you like I can update the example with the html you have.